# Session closed error when performing subsequence requests to client via Spring RestTemplate

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I'm trying to use spring rest template to do a post request to login in.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> mvm = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
mvm.add("LoginForm_Login", "login");
mvm.add("LoginForm_Password", "password");

ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(uriDWLogin, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
```

all goes well, but when I try to send a second request, It generates an error saying :

> Business Manager closes your session after 15 minutes

What can I do to solve this problem ?!

Comment: i think this is a normal response from the server you are trying to reach.This is not a problem with Spring RestTemplate.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not a problem with RestTemplate, I must keep the session active ...

Comment: For starters, why send a second login request when the user is already logged in. Secondly, if you still wanna do it, you must change session management strategy on server side. 15 minutes session is just too low.

Comment: The second request is to download the data from the (CMS) because I can't do it without login ...

Comment: Then in your 2nd request, you must set the cookies as mentioned in the answer by Nikolay. This way, spring-security knows that it's an authenticated user. You Can save the cookie at login. I will post some code which you can use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you receive the response in your first request  you should store your `session id` which is received via cookie. You will retrieve it in a `set-cookie` response header which you can get via:

```
//first request
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> forEntity = template.getForEntity("http://google.bg", String.class);
forEntity.getHeaders().get("Set-Cookie").stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

then in every subsequent request you should set the `Cookie` request header with the values received in the first request:

```
//subsequent request
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Cookie",cookies.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(";")));
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
restTemplate.exchange("http://url", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

Comment: If you directly get the `Set-Cookie` values and store them in a String array which you later on put into the `headers`-`Cookie` then you will have `;path=...` or similar values which will make your cookies invalid. But I like the example you gave above, it helped my much

Comment: Can't the first request simply save the Cookie and then be reused? Why create a new one?

Answer (score 0):

I have a StaticRestTemplate class, this way I get the same RestTemplate instance.

```
public class StaticRestTemplate {

    public volatile static RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
 public static volatile String jsessionid = "";    
// This way, I can test on local or server just  by changing one URL.
public static volatile String baseURL = "http://192.168.178.60:8080/";
}
```

Login code :

```
   public static RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
  rest.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            StaticRestTemplate.jsessionid = rest.execute(StaticRestTemplate.baseURL+"j_spring_security_check", HttpMethod.POST,
                    new RequestCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void doWithRequest(ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                            request.getBody().write(("j_username=" + email + "&j_password=" + password).getBytes());
                        }
                    }, new ResponseExtractor<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                            List<String> cookies = response.getHeaders().get("Cookie");
                            if (cookies == null) {
                                cookies = response.getHeaders().get("Set-Cookie");
                            }
                            String cookie = cookies.get(cookies.size() - 1);
                            int start = cookie.indexOf('=');
                            int end = cookie.indexOf(';');

                            return cookie.substring(start + 1, end);
                        }
                    });
            return null;

        }
```

Now, my JsessionID is saved, and I can use it directly for subsequent requests this way :

```
rest.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
// This is where I add the cookie value
            requestHeaders.add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + StaticRestTemplate.jsessionid);
            HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);

            HttpEntity<String> rssResponse = rest.exchange(
                    StaticRestTemplate.baseURL+"dashboard",
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    requestEntity,
                    String.class);
            StaticRestTemplate.replyString = rssResponse.getBody();
            return StaticRestTemplate.replyString;
```

If there are doubts, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable cookie management with factory for your RestTemplate:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                    .disableCookieManagement()
                    .useSystemProperties()
                    .build();
    factory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
```